# Density of sections of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, submersions

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, $f:V \to X$ be a (real) vector bundle and $g:V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a submersion for some $n>0$ (here $n$ is *not* the same as the dimension of the fiber of the vector bundle $V$). Clearly, $g^{-1}(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ is dense in $V$. My question is: does there exist $x \in X$, such that $g^{-1}(\mathbb{Q}^n) \cap f^{-1}(x)$ is dense in $f^{-1}(x)$?

Any hint/idea will be most welcome.

Comment: Suppose $n=2m$, $X=\mathbb{C}^m$, and $f=g$.

Comment: I think you need $\text{ker}(df)$ and $\text{ker}(dg)$ to span $TV$ and each point. If you think about e.g. $V=\mathbb R^3$, $n=dim(X)=2$ and $g$ is just projection, then the preimage of $Q^2$ will be a dense set of lines all in the same direction, and any other linear projections to $R^2$ will also have fibers that miss these lines. So you really do need the tangent spaces of the fibers to span.

Comment: @DonuArapura I have edited the question. Could you please comment on the edited question.